# Twitter Bootstrap and PSDs of Different Sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried but could not find a satisfactory answer. I want to use Twitter bootstrap to make my designs responsive. I get PSDs in different sizes i.e. 1200, 1024, 980, 960 etc and I create a #wrap of 1200, 1024, 980, 960 accordingly and then do all design within that wrap. I am confused about Bootstrap. My question is can I apply Responsive bootstrap only on PSD that is designed on BootStrap Grid or can i use responsive bootstrap on any sized PSD? If Yes then how can I use it with every PSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap is using certain breakpoints to change the appearence on different devices - some detailed information: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

The 'normal' bootstrap version has 12 cols but you can redefine the ColumnWidth and the gutterWidth. There are also 16 cols bootstrap versions like http://lightglitch.github.com/bootstrap-xtra/ or even 24 cols grids - try google.

So best practice, from PSD to HTML would be, for me, to do the designs in the intended grids and media resolutions, and to suggest that at the start of a new project to the designer.

The harder way would be: Look how bootstrap did it, and build your own little framework to fit with your PSD.